# stopPropagation Not Working in Content Script of Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a simple Chrome extension that allows users to highlight certain elements on a page by clicking on them. However, in the case that a user clicks on a link or any other element that loads new content, I want to be able to prevent the propagation of the click so that both links and any other elements with click handlers are not triggered. I am currently using `event.preventDefault()` to stop links from firing when clicked but `event.stopPropagation()` is not preventing element click handlers from being triggered. Can anyone tell me why this might be?

Here is my `content.js`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault(); //this works for links
   event.stopPropagation(); //this does not work
   some_func_here();
});
```

In my `background.js` script, `content.js` is loaded by:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'content.js'});
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since you attached the event listener to `document`, your code doesn't run until the event has already bubbled all the way up. It's too late to stop propagation, it has already propagated.

Comment: @Barmar That makes sense, however, `event.preventDefault()` blocks hrefs from firing. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: Because default actions don't take place until all the bubbling has completed. Any of them can prevent the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally event propagation bubbles up from the target element to `document`. By the time the event has propagated to `document`, where your listener is attached, it's too late to stop propagation to the target and intermediate elements.

However, there's a little known feature called "capturing", during which the event propagates down from `document` to the target element. You can use the `{capture: true}` option to `addEventListener` to indicate that the handler should be attached to the capturing phase.

If you use this, you can stop propagation down to the element.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault(); //this works for links
   event.stopPropagation(); //this does not work
   some_func_here();
}, {capture: true});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. I was not aware of the `capture` option.